# Is the Excel sheet name available in a Pandas DataFrame object?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I'm using Pandas `read_excel` method to read an Excel file into a `DataFrame`. I specify the name of the sheet when I read it in-- but I'd like very much to be able to get that sheet name back from the `DataFrame` object. Is this information recorded somewhere in the object?

Comment: with the ExcelFile class, you can get the sheet names : [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#excelfile-class)

Comment: To be clear, I'm looking for the availability of that sheet name in the DataFrame object itself.... so I can recover it later when it's passed to  different namespace.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do / what is the end goal?

Comment: What's an XY problem?

Comment: I'm trying to read an Excel file with Pandas, pass the info into a function, and record that information into a class. Specifically, I need the column headings, the sheet name, and the contents. I got access to everything except the sheet name from the dataframe itself.

Comment: [What is the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would a `DataFrame` "care" about the sheet name? Excel is just one of many sources from which a `DataFrame` can be constructed. Why do you think what you're looking for would be implemented? Which suggests this is an XY problem, and the real solution lies elsewhere.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Fair enough. I mean I could just pass the sheet name into my method as an extra variable.... just wanted to make sure that it wasn't already contained somewhere in the dataframe.

Comment: `pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)` returns a dictionary `{sheet_name: dataframe}`. Does that work for you?

Comment: This isn't an XY problem. A pandas dataframe contains metadata that identifies its origin. This is useful in error reporting, to direct the user to the location of the offending data. E.g. at each row from `iterrows`, the row index is available in the `name` attribute. Asking "why does the dataframe care what sheet it came from?", is similar to asking "Why does a row of data care what index it came from?".  The answer is the same: so you can find that data in its source. Therefore, since it is done in the smaller context, it's a reasonable question to ask about the larger context.